# Implement Euler method in python

Tags: python, overflow

I'm trying to implement Euler's method to calculate a sequence of numbers with python, but the problem is N is big (10000000). And python keeps telling me overflow.
Does anyone know a better way to calculate this?

```
def facto(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
     else:
        return n*facto(n-1)

def exp(x, n):
   my_sum = 0.0
   for i in range(n+1):
     my_sum += (x**i)/facto(i)
   return my_sum

def r(n):
    return int(exp(x, n)*n)/n
```

for i in range(1,N):
print(r(i))

#facto is the function I use to calculate the factorial of a number

re

Comment: 1) Should properly indent code and 2) Missing function facto.

Comment: you'r right.  I'm going to fix that

Comment: @zack22--are you getting overflow or recursion depth exceeded?  I would expect recursion depth exceeded in facto due to it's recursive definition.  That's why it's recommended to provide the complete error message so we can see the specifics including the line number it occurs.

Comment: I have just changed my recursive version of the facto function. Now here is the error I have :
 File "/Users/zackhenri/Desktop/test.py", line 15, in exp
    my_sum += (x**i)/facto(i)
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Comment: @zack22--in function `r`,  x is not defined i.e. `return int(exp(x, n)*n)/n`.

Answer (score 0):

Issues with code:

1. function r(n) should have x as input i.e. `def r(x, n):`
2. function exp, Line `my_sum += (x**i)/facto(i)` gets the error OverflowError: int too large to convert to float for example when N = 1000
3. facto is recursive so will reach maximum recursion depth at n ~ 1,000.

**Option 1--Use logarithm for division**

```
import math

def facto(n):
    ' Iterative calculation for factorial to prevent reaching max recursion depth which occurs for n ~ 1000 '
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result *= i
        
    return result

def log_divide(num, denom):
    ' Division using log function '
    return math.exp(math.log(num) - math.log(denom))  # subtract to logs, then exponentiate

def exp(x, n):
    my_sum = 0.0
    for i in range(n+1):
        my_sum += log_divide(x**i, facto(i))
    return my_sum

def r(x, n):
    return int(exp(x, n)*n)/n
```

**Option 2--use Decimal module which allows arbitrary precision**

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 50                        # Set precision for decimal arithmetic

def facto(n):
    ' Iterative calculation for factorial to prevent reaching max recursion depth which occurs for n ~ 1000 '
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result *= i
        
    return result

def exp(x, n):
   my_sum = Decimal(0.0)
   for i in range(n+1):
     my_sum += Decimal((x**i))/Decimal(facto(i))
    
   return my_sum


def r(x, n):
    return int(exp(x, n)*n)/n
```

**Usage**

Both versions work for N == 1000:

```
r(1.0, 1000)
Out: 2.718
```

Answer (score 0):

The factorial gets very fast very large. Instead of calculation the factorial for each term, it is much easier to calculate the next term from the previous one:

```
def exp(x, n):
    r = 1
    result = 1.0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        r *= x/i
        result += r
    return result
```